# Is is correct to say "future prospects"?

Tags: pleonasms

Prospect means the likelihood of a future event occurring. Although I have seen this many times, even in my questions for an essay, or as the name of a company, I doubt about the usage of this collocation. I believe it is pleonastic and circumlocutory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a peeve

Comment: To most people it's more "correct" to say "future prospects" than it is to say "collocation" or "pleonastic and circumlocutory".

Comment: It's fine and dandy.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the usage is pleonastic. The word prospects is being used to mean:

> The outlook for the future.

[Noun. 1.b](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/prospect)

Therefore prefixing prospects with the word 'future' is redundant.